# UPDATE query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php code on page purchase_form1

```
<?php
include_once("includes/form_functions.php");
$id = 0;
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['id'] != ''))
{
$id = (int)htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
}
$query  = "SELECT * from db_purchase_form where id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$has_data = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $has_data = true;
    $product_name = $row[1];
    $choice_actor = $row[2];
    $user_name = $row[3];
    $user_email = $row[4];
    $vdo_script = $row[5];
    $hrt_msg = $row[6];
    $portApproval = $row[7];
    $delivery = $row[8];
    $net_price = $row[9];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($has_data == true)
    {
        $sql  = "UPDATE db_purchase_form SET ";
        $sql .= "db_product_name = '" . $product_name . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_actor = '" . $choice_actor . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_user_name = '" . $user_name . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_user_email = '" . $user_email . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_vdo_script = '" . $vdo_script . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_hrt_msg = '" . $hrt_msg . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_port_approval = '" . $portApproval . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_delivery = '" . $delivery . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_price = '" . $net_price . "', ";
        $sql .= "db_date_time = NOW() ";
        $sql .= "WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    }
    else
    { // validation for form purchaseform and insert into DB if all is good.

            if(empty($message)) // $,message i used for errors. This line means if all validations above are okay
        {
            $insert = // INSERT INTO MYSQL DB
            $result = mysql_query($insert);
            if($result)
            {
                $lastInsertedId =  mysql_insert_id();
                $timestamp = time();
                      header('Location:purchase_form1_conf.php?'.http_build_query(array('id' => $lastInsertedId,'time' => $timestamp,'hash' => sha1('some-generated-key'.$timestamp.$lastInsertedId))));
            }
            else
            {
                $message = "The data cannot be inserted.";
                $message .= "<br />" . mysql_error();
            }
                    }
```

below on the page is this HTML code for the form

```
             <?php  //here i display errors
                        if(!empty($message))
                        {
                            echo "<p style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>" . $message . "</p>";
                        }
             ?>
                    <form id="PurchaseForm" name="PurchaseForm" method="post" action="purchase_form1.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"> //this is starting of form.
                   // actual html form, set for fields using php, the form is very long 
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now" class="button3">
                </form>
```

NOW I SEND THE DATA TO purchase_form1_conf.php. purchase_form1_conf.php IS THE DISPLAY PAGE, IT DISPLAYS THE FORM DATA AND IF USER CLICKS ON EDIT BUTTON, HE IS TAKEN BACK TO purchase_form1.php.

PHP CODE FOR purchase_form1_conf.php

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
$time = $_GET['time'];
if($_GET['hash'] != sha1('some-generated-key'.$time.$id))
die('URL was tampered with');
//if(time() - $time > 300)
//die('URL was only valid for 5 minutes');

//}
//if (isset($_GET['id']))
//{
//$lastInsertedId = $_GET['id'];
//}
//$id = $_SESSION['last_id'];
//$query  = "SELECT * FROM db_purchase_form WHERE id=$lastInsertedId";
//$result = mysql_query($query);
//while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

if ($id)
{
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM db_purchase_form WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $product_name = $row[1];
        $choice_actor = $row[2];
        $user_name = $row[3];
        $user_email = $row[4];
        $vdo_script = $row[5];
        $hrt_msg = $row[6];
        $portApproval = $row[7];
        $delivery = $row[8];
        $net_price = $row[9];
    }
}
?>
```

// NOW HERE I DISPLAYS THE VALUES AS I GET FROM DB AS $row[1], 2 SO ON AND THERE ARE TWO BUTTONS ON THIS PAGE,ONE IS EDIT BUTTON AND OTHER IS PAYPAL, BUT IT IS NOT THE FORM, IT IS JUST A DIV DISPLAYING THE VALUES PULLED FROM DB,

THE CODE FOR EDIT BUTTON IS

```
<a href="purchase_form1.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="button4">Edit</a>
```

IT TAKES USER TO purchase_form1.php.

NOW WHAT IS THE ISSUE?

when user if on purchase_form1.php page, he sees a fresh form. The url this time is,
http://site.com/purchase_form1.php

**he fills the from, clicks submit, if errors, he is shown message for the error, he removes errors and again click submit and then he is taken to next page i.e purchase_form1_conf.php.**

the url for next page is

http://site.com/purchase_form1_conf.php?id=54&time=1376047215&hash=cbaaabbcf8b20de044b9dd105cae60d1f1ab5b92

all seems good.

now when he sees the form and he want to change the value, he clikcs on edit, and he is taken to earlier page the form page and the url is
http://site.com/purchase_form1.php?id=54

see the id =54 in both the pages. Till here all seems perfect.

**Now actual issue,
when on this page purchase_form1.php he edits the form, and clicks submit, neither the URL changes, nor DB is updated, nothing happens.**

What shall be happening instead? the DB shall be updating, and the user shall be taken to the next page again, with the new data. But it is not.

Comment: your idea of update is quite a strange one. Why do you select first?

Comment: and... sorry, but I managed to get only 1/3 of this novel.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what you did not managed to get?

Comment: Too much text here, your errors are not checking whether the query succeeds and you reversed parameters in your mysql_query(). It's query first, connection second as parameters.

Comment: @N.B. can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: I already did, I won't spoon feed you. You got the symptoms, you got possible remedy, figure the rest out on your own.

Comment: As some other comments "suggested" it your question is probably too long. In order to obtain interesting answers, you should probably narrow down your problem, read the [*Stack Overflow question checklist*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and then edit the text accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see where you are executing your UPDATE STATEMENT.

```
    $sql  = "UPDATE db_purchase_form SET ";
    $sql .= "db_product_name = '" . $product_name . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_actor = '" . $choice_actor . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_user_name = '" . $user_name . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_user_email = '" . $user_email . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_vdo_script = '" . $vdo_script . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_hrt_msg = '" . $hrt_msg . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_port_approval = '" . $portApproval . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_delivery = '" . $delivery . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_price = '" . $net_price . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_date_time = NOW() ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    **mysqli_query($conexionObj, $sql);**
```

Comment: so what shall i be doing instead?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation on the function you're trying to execute to see the proper order of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Improve the following code in where clause in update statement

```
     $sql  = "UPDATE db_purchase_form SET ";
    $sql .= "db_product_name = '" . $product_name . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_actor = '" . $choice_actor . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_user_name = '" . $user_name . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_user_email = '" . $user_email . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_vdo_script = '" . $vdo_script . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_hrt_msg = '" . $hrt_msg . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_port_approval = '" . $portApproval . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_delivery = '" . $delivery . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_price = '" . $net_price . "', ";
    $sql .= "db_date_time = NOW() ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id = $id ";
```